# Unable to access URL property of an <object> element (Javascript\jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame, html-object

I have a problem of being unable to access data contained in the object corresponding to an `<object>`-html element which is used **to display another website**. The use-case scenario is that I want to display external website within my page and I want **to know on which links users click (within this integrated external website)**

Specifically, I am interested in the *URL* or in the *name* of the document. When I try to get this data (which I can see when I browse through the object using firebug) I am unable to do it. Somehow access is restricted or I do something wrong.

Here is exactly what I am doing.

1) I define an object with a wikipedia article as a data source

```
<object id='wikiframe' data='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/thing' width='100%' height='700px'> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>
```

2) I define a click event for the document in order to know when user clicks

```
$(function() {
    document.onclick = myClickHandler;
    function myClickHandler() {
        // Please help to assign a string with the wikipedia article name or with the string of url of the link which was clicked to the variable articleName;
        var articleName;
        var wikiObject = $("#wikiframe");
        alert('The name of the currenttly opened wiki article is: ' + articleName);
    }
});
```

Now here are the problems:

1) If I click within the article, click event does not fire.
2) I cannot access the data contained in the object corresponding to this  element. But there is information I need in it as you see on the screenshot.

On the screenshot you see a wikipedia article which was opened by clicking on a link within the article which was first displayed. Firebug displays the information I need (in this case the URL to the article "Noumenon"

[Link to image displaying the properties I want to access http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/3217/informationcontainedino.png](http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/3217/informationcontainedino.png)

Can you please help by telling me what I need to add in order to assign `articleName` a string with the url of the clicked link.

The whole code is here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    If you click anywhere except the object click event fires. If you click on object it does not. I want the click event firing on clicking within wiki article and showing either a) the name of currently opened article OR b) the url of the clicked link
    <object id='wikiframe' data='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/thing' width='100%' height='700px'> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed. </object>
</body>

<script>
    $(function() {
        document.onclick = myClickHandler;
        function myClickHandler() {
            // Please help to assign a string with the wikipedia article name to the variable articleName;
            var articleName;
            var wikiObject = $("#wikiframe");
            alert('The name of the currenttly opened wiki article is: ' + articleName);
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Actually, you can't because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: There must be a way to access it if the data is there and the browser can access it too.

Comment: trying to comprehend why can't you do this
var datalink = $('#wikiframe').attr('data');

Comment: @JamesDaly That works for the URL, but not for any document property like the title, due to security restrictions.

Comment: @James Daly: That was my first idea. But if you do so you will always get the original value. As soon as you changed the content of a page by clicking on a link document.URI will change but not the data property.

Comment: so what does change - can you fire a function for each click event $('a').on('click', function () {
    //
})
i guess it's hard to comprehend w/o link

Comment: i'm essentially going to regurgitate what bfavaretto said because essentially your going to run into the same origin policy given that there are some workarounds depending on the situation so please check out this link http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: @James: As I said, I can not fire click events when clicking on the '<object>'-element. And thanks for the link. I have to find a workaround...

Comment: No can do. Simply like that. The first comment is actually the answer to your question.